# Can't show translated .zip files on Autodesk Viewer after translating them with Forge APIs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I've tried following the [tutorial on how to translate .zip files](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/) sending all the requests using Postman. Everything went smoothly with no errors and the responses where all as they were supposed to be. In the end I saved the response as a .stl file but when I try to visualize it on the [online Autodesk Viewer](https://viewer.autodesk.com) it says that the model is empty.

I've been trying several times this tutorial, and on different Forge apps now but the result is always the same. Except for one time where Autodesk Viewer visualized what seemed like a single object of the file Tuner.zip.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are a couple of requirements when processing a **collection of files** with the Model Derivative service:

- you must include all the required files (for example, the main Inventor assembly file as well as all the Inventor part files that are referenced by it) in the zip
- the files in the zip archive should *not* be in any subfolders
- when submitting the Model Derivative [job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST), you have to include the `compressedUrn` and `rootFilename` parameters

Comment: If you follow all these requirements and you still can't get the output, feel free to contact us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, if possible, sharing the zip file you are trying to translate (we will not share it with anyone outside of Autodesk).

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn't the step-by-step tutorial ignore these requirements? It simply specifies the name of the .zip and .iam files. Anyway, I am working with the same "Tuner.zip" file used in the tutorial.

Comment: Solved, I had some issues with file format during it's download. Thank you for your time anyways!